# Filtering GML data by attributes (not attr.value) on the server side for calling them with http protocol, Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, filter

Supposedely it is easy but I can't figure it out:
How to get data from server (format: gml) which contains all features but not all of the attributes?

I have really big data and it is important just to call the relevant of them on a single click, because otherwise the loading time is inacceptable.

At the moment I call the data with http protocol, like:

```
 var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: 'path to the gml file', 
                format: gml
                });

var vectorLayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector ('layer', {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: protocol,
        styleMap: styleMap,
        rendererOptions: {zIndexing: true}
        });
```

I assume that I should use the filterToParams method, however, I don't understand it exactly how it works.

It would be great if somebody could post me a fictious example. I mean what should I do, when I just want to have all features and the attribute "att1" to the features, but not any other attributes?

It would be a great help!

Comment: I'm not sure how you implement it in OL but this page (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature) gives you the format of the requests

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the attributes with a comma-separated list of values for propertyName like:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
  featureID=feature&
  propertyName=attribute1,attribute2
```

The attributes **attribute1** and **attribute2** will be returned.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I can't apply them to my situtation, because the data don't come via wfs service but they are saved as a gml file on the server. So it should be treated like an xml file. Do you have maybe a suggestion how to access the attributes in that case?

Comment: Did you try? `var gml = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
gml.featureName="attribute1"`